# debug exercise fixed everything wont run right passed get first name

Tags: c#

I have fixed all that I knew how to fix I don't know why it wont go passed get user first name. This is using visual studio 2015

```
using System;
public class DebugTwo2
{
       public static void Main()
       {
            string name;
            string firstString, secondString;
            int first, second, product;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");  
            name = Console.ReadLine();           //this is as far as it runs
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {}! Enter an integer", name);
            firstString = Console.ReadLine();
            first = Convert.ToInt32(firstString);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another integer");
            secondString = Console.ReadLine();
            second = Convert.ToInt32(secondString);
            product = first * second;
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you {}. The product of {1} and {2} is {3}",
            name, first, second, product);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the number between the braces:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}! Enter an integer", name);
```

It's zero-based so with 2 arguments it would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}{1}! Enter an integer", firstName, name);
```

With C#6 there is a new way for formatting strings too, using the `$` sign to allow in-line variables (which is more readable if there are many arguments in my opinion):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}! Enter an integer");
```

You don't even need to declare `product` anymore that way:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Thank you {name}. The product of {first} and {second} is {first*second}");
```

Comment: The "Thank you" line also has the same issue.